# Bash script freezes when sent SIGINT

Tags: bash

I finally grew tired of makefiles and wrote my own bash script to do my compiling.  I wrote the whole thing, it works great, but for some reason, it freezes sometimes when I try to cancel it with ctrl-c.  Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Just to see if the script even sees the SIGINT
trap caught SIGINT
caught() { echo "hi"; }

compile() {
    cpp=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/$/.cpp/' -e 's/^/src\//')
    o=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/$/.o/' -e "s/^/$build_dir\//")
    echo "$compile -c $cpp -o $o"
    eval "$compile -c $cpp -o $o"
    return $?
}

# I know this isn't normal, but I hate it when I forget to include something
# in the header and it fails way down the line
compile_h() {
    h=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/$/.h/' -e 's/^/src\//')
    o=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/$/.o/' -e "s/^/$build_dir\/headers\//")
    echo "$compile -c $h -o /dev/null"
    eval "$compile -x c++ -c $h -o $o"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    rm "$o"
    return 0
}

build_type=$(awk 'NR==1' .build_options)
compile_command_debug=$(awk 'NR==2' .build_options)
link_command_debug=$(awk 'NR==3' .build_options)
compile_command_production=$(awk 'NR==4' .build_options)
link_command_production=$(awk 'NR==5' .build_options)
libraries=$(awk 'NR==6' .build_options)

# Make options for this build
build_dir="build"
compile="$compile_command_debug"
link="$link_command_debug"
if [ "$build_type" == "production" ]; then
    build_dir="buildp"
    compile="$compile_command_production"
    link="$link_command_production"
fi
# These options need to be changeable later
output="game"
job_number=5

# There are more options, but they aren't important for this problem
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    if [ "$1" == "clean" ]; then
        rm -r $build_dir/*
    fi
    shift
done

# Get filenames
cpps=$(find src -name *.cpp | sed -e 's/src\///' -e 's/.cpp//' | sort)
hs=$(find src -name *.h | sed -e 's/src\///' -e 's/.h//' | sort)

# Ensure that all directories exist
directories=$(find src -type d | tail --lines=+2 | sed 's/src\///' | sort)
if [ ! -d "$build_dir/headers" ]; then
    mkdir "$build_dir/headers"
fi
for dir in $directories; do
    if [ ! -d "$build_dir/$dir" ]; then
        mkdir "$build_dir/$dir"
    fi
    if [ ! -d "$build_dir/headers/$dir" ]; then
        mkdir "$build_dir/headers/$dir"
    fi
done

all_o="" # To be used for linking
# Determine what files need to be compiled
cpp_needed=""
h_needed=""
link_needed=false
# Check cpp files
for cpp_base in $cpps; do
    o=$(echo "$cpp_base" | sed -e 's/$/.o/' -e "s/^/$build_dir\//")
    all_o="$all_o $o"
    d_file=$(echo "$cpp_base" | sed -e 's/$/.d/' -e "s/^/$build_dir\//")
    if [ -f "$d_file" ]; then
        d=$(<"$d_file")
        d=$(echo "$d" | tr " " "\n" | tail --lines=+2 | grep "s")
        if [ "$link_needed" = false ]; then
            if [ "$o" -nt "$output" ]; then
                link_needed=true
            fi
        fi
        for dep in $d; do
            if [ "$dep" -nt "$o" ]; then
                if [ "$cpp_needed" == "" ]; then cpp_needed="$cpp_base"
                else cpp_needed="$cpp_needed $cpp_base"
                fi
                link_needed=true
                break
            fi
        done
    else
        if [ "$cpp_needed" == "" ]; then cpp_needed="$cpp_base"
        else cpp_needed="$cpp_needed $cpp_base"
        fi
        link_needed=true
    fi
done
# Check h files
for h_base in $hs; do
    d_file=$(echo "$h_base" | sed -e 's/$/.d/' -e "s/^/$build_dir\/headers\//")
    if [ -f "$d_file" ]; then
        d=$(<"$d_file")
        d=$(echo "$d" | tr " " "\n" | tail --lines=+2 | grep "s")
        for dep in $d; do
            if [ "$dep" -nt "$d_file" ]; then
                if [ "$h_needed" == "" ]; then h_needed="$h_base"
                else h_needed="$h_needed $h_base"
                fi
                break
            fi
        done
    else
        if [ "$h_needed" == "" ]; then h_needed="$h_base"
        else h_needed="$h_needed $h_base"
        fi
    fi
done

# Compile
did_something=false
# Compile hs
while [ "$h_needed" != "" ]; do
    for index in $(seq 1 $job_number); do
        if [ "$h_needed" == "" ]; then break; fi
        if ! kill -0 ${pids[index]} 2>/dev/null; then
            new_file=$(echo "$h_needed" | awk '{print $1;}')
            if [ $(echo "$h_needed" | wc -w) -eq 1 ]; then h_needed=""
            else h_needed=$(echo "$h_needed" | cut -d " " -f2-)
            fi
            compile_h "$new_file" &
            pids[index]=$!
            did_something=true
        fi
    done
    wait -n
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        wait
        exit 1
    fi
done
while [ $(pgrep -c -P$$) -gt 0 ]; do
    wait -n
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        wait
        exit 1
    fi
done

# Compile cpps
while [ "$cpp_needed" != "" ]; do
    for index in $(seq 1 $job_number); do
        if [ "$cpp_needed" == "" ]; then break; fi
        if ! kill -0 ${pids[index]} 2>/dev/null; then
            new_file=$(echo "$cpp_needed" | awk '{print $1;}')
            if [ $(echo "$cpp_needed" | wc -w) -eq 1 ]; then cpp_needed=""
            else cpp_needed=$(echo "$cpp_needed" | cut -d " " -f2-)
            fi
            compile "$new_file" &
            pids[index]=$!
            did_something=true
        fi
    done
    wait -n
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        wait
        exit 1
    fi
done
while [ $(pgrep -c -P$$) -gt 0 ]; do
    wait -n
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        wait
        exit 1
    fi
done

# Compile program
if [ "$link_needed" = true ]; then
    echo "$link $all_o -o game $libraries"
    eval "$link $all_o -o game $libraries"
    did_something=true
fi
# Make a message if nothing compiled
if [ "$did_something" = false ]; then
    echo "Program is already compiled."
fi
```

It normally works perfectly.  However, sometimes, when I try to cancel it with ctrl-c it just freezes.  With a bit of debugging I saw that when the script wasn't setting up a new job, ctrl-c would work just fine.  But when it was in the middle of setting up a new job, it would freeze the script.  It wouldn't even catch the SIGINT (which that "echo hi" thing is for at the top).  I honestly have no idea what's going on.  Does anybody know what's going on?  Thank you!

Edit: I realized I should probably mention I use g++ to compile.

Edit again: Here's an even-more stripped down version of the script.  You would still need to setup some files to compile if you wanted to test it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Just to see if the script even sees the SIGINT
trap caught SIGINT
caught() { echo "hi"; }

# I know this isn't normal, but I hate it when I forget to include something
# in the header and it fails way down the line
compile_h() {
    h=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/$/.h/' -e 's/^/src\//')
    o=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/$/.o/' -e "s/^/$build_dir\/headers\//")
    echo "$compile -c $h -o /dev/null"
    eval "$compile -x c++ -c $h -o $o"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        return 1
    fi
    rm "$o"
    return 0
}

build_type="debug"
build_dir="build"
compile="g++"
job_number=5

# Get filenames
hs=$(find src -name *.h | sed -e 's/src\///' -e 's/.h//' | sort)
h_needed=$(echo $hs)

# Compile hs
while [ "$h_needed" != "" ]; do
    for index in $(seq 1 $job_number); do
        if [ "$h_needed" == "" ]; then break; fi
        if ! kill -0 ${pids[index]} 2>/dev/null; then
            new_file=$(echo "$h_needed" | awk '{print $1;}')
            if [ $(echo "$h_needed" | wc -w) -eq 1 ]; then h_needed=""
            else h_needed=$(echo "$h_needed" | cut -d " " -f2-)
            fi
            compile_h "$new_file" &
            pids[index]=$!
            did_something=true
        fi
    done
    wait -n
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        wait
        exit 1
    fi
done
while [ $(pgrep -c -P$$) -gt 0 ]; do
    wait -n
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        wait
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: Try understand the [mcve]. In this case, especially the "minimal" word :)

Comment: ... also, it is sure better to use configure + makefile as your own invented solution... (just imho).

Comment: I already got rid of a lot of stuff from my actual version.  The problem is that I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I used that to figure out that when it freezes.  The debug output says nothing when it freezes.

Comment: "I finally grew tired of makefiles and wrote my own bash script to do my compiling." That seems like a step back towards the days of caves and rocks and clubs...

Comment: You need to spend some time learning `bash`. For example, `cpp=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/$/.cpp/' -e 's/^/src\//')` is written *much* more simply `cpp=/src/$1.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Any program that you run in your script may override your trap and set up its own. That trap might for example crash the currently running program for some reason. When this happens, take a look at the process tree in `ps wafux` to find the most likely culprit. For example, a zombie (`Z`) or uninterruptible sleep (`D`) process state (see `man ps`) is common when a process isn't going anywhere.

Comment: All of the child g++'s are gone, but the script itself is at the state of "R+", which it says means it's still running.